Swal Load Vue Component
I'm implementing SweetAlert2 in my Laravel Vue project and I want to load a Vue component inside a swal modal.
I've tried passing a VueComponent directly into the html tag inside Swal options.
    Swal.fire({
        html: "<VueComponent></VueComponent>"
    })

Is this possible?

This wouldn't make much sense because this disables all the interactivity of a component and uses vue as template engine. You could potentially mount vue subapp or teleport to Swal.getHtmlContainer() element, this depends on your case
